# Randomly Assign Value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, computer-science

I am working on a program that is supposed to assign a female dancer partner to a male dance partner. The user selects a male dancer and the program should randomly assign a female dancer, and then remove both of the chosen dancers from the original list. In my coding class, I was never taught how to randomly assign like this. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import random


maledancers = {"Maciek", "Marek", "Marcel", "Carson", "Brett", "Connor"}
femaledancers = {"Renata", "Karolina", "Maja", "Natalia", "Olivia", "Meghan"}



print("You will be pairing the male dancers with the female dancers.")
print("You will select one of the male dancers and it will get paired with a female dancer randomly")

dancer = input("Out of the male dancers, please select one to be paired: ")

if dancer not in maledancers:
    print("Your choice is not in the list of dancers, please re-enter a dancer from the list")
if dancer in maledancers:
    print("Great we will now randomly give " + dancer + " a partner to dance with")
if dancer.isdigit():
    print("The dancer can't have any numbers in their name. Try again please!")
```

If anyone has any input as to what I can do here, I'd really appreciate any help. If you answer this question, please show the change in code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
import random


maledancers = {"Maciek", "Marek", "Marcel", "Carson", "Brett", "Connor"}
femaledancers = {"Renata", "Karolina", "Maja", "Natalia", "Olivia", "Meghan"}


print("You will be pairing the male dancers with the female dancers.")
print(
    "You will select one of the male dancers and it will get paired with a female dancer randomly"
)

for i in range(len(maledancers)):

    dancer = input("Out of the male dancers, please select one to be paired: ")

    if dancer not in maledancers:
        print(
            "Your choice is not in the list of dancers, please re-enter a dancer from the list"
        )

    if dancer in maledancers:
        print("Great we will now randomly give " + dancer + " a partner to dance with")

        # get a random female
        random_female = random.choice(list(femaledancers))
        # remove that female and male
        femaledancers.remove(random_female)
        maledancers.remove(dancer)

        # do wtevr u want with this female now
```

I would suggest to use lists, instead of sets to avoid the frequent conversion to list while selecting random females.

Also not sure why you had that last if statement, about `isdigit`.

Comment: Hey thanks for this input. The last if statement is just something extra doesn't really need to be there. I also would want this program to remove the random_female and the user input from the list of dancers and store them into another list called dance_partners. Could you run me through that as well. Ill try to do it and ill comment again what I did on my own.

Comment: Sure. you could just use the `.remove` method to remove a value from a set. edited the post…

Comment: @MaciekB, you can  just loop len(dancers) number of times. edited the post :). Altho i get the feeling you are making me do your homework :O

Comment: You better accept my answer now

Comment: Wow. Totally terrible move to have done the homework and not get credit for the answer! Bad move @Hypnotix999